# mySQL error 'Trying to access array offset on value of type null'

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a node.js project but I'm using XAMPP to host my db and phpmyadmin in order to see the data and administrate it. The thing is today a table started showing me this error whenever I open it, and my bot crashes if it make a query for it, and it's just this table. I tested with other commands that require querys but they work just fine.
Thank you!

```
Notice in .\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#4439
 Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Backtrace

.\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php#4197: PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getSortedColumnMessage(
,
string '`tieBreakerMatchNeeded`',
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#1666: PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTable(
,
array,
array,
boolean true,
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#1468: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
array,
boolean false,
integer 0,
integer 0,
boolean true,
,
array,
boolean true,
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#2250: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getQueryResponseForNoResultsReturned(
array,
string 'torneos_wild_gaming',
string 'matches',
NULL,
integer 0,
,
NULL,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
,
string 'SELECT * FROM `matches` ORDER BY `tieBreakerMatchNeeded` ASC ',
NULL,
)
.\libraries\classes\Sql.php#2100: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'torneos_wild_gaming',
string 'matches',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `matches` ORDER BY `tieBreakerMatchNeeded` ASC ',
NULL,
NULL,
)
.\sql.php#241: PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'torneos_wild_gaming',
string 'matches',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `matches`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Comment: PD: I tried copying it from the backup I had but it still fails.

Comment: That's a PHP error, you need to show the relevant PHP script.

Comment: The thing is I have no PHP error since everything has been done in nodejs.
I will leave the nodejs file that interacts with that table.
https://hastebin.com/xozikaqafi.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a backup. It seems was a problem with XAMPP or PHPMyAdmin.